# Is there a better way to write this ifs statement?

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace

I’m making a calculator for fun in relation to a Roleplay group of mine. Essential a certain number, to number, equals another number. However, the way I’m writing it seems inefficient as I have been writing each number one by one like so:

```
=ifs(A13=1,-2,A13=2,-2,A13=3,-1,A13=4,-1,A13=10,3,len(A13)=0,A1)
```

Where A13 is the cell where people input their numbers. I was wondering if there was some way to go about this better? An example of how this works is:

1-4 = 1

5-8 = 2

9-12 = 3...etc.

Is there a way to write Number To Number ? Or any suggestions for how I could go about doing this better?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please follow the [tour], read [ask], add a brief description of your search/research efforts and try to reword your question as it's actually worded it looks like a primarily opinion-based questions which are not allowed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like some arithmetic does the job, something like this:

- add 3 to the number, divide by 4 and round down. The following formula does that (the round down is performed by the [`INT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093490?hl=en) function):

  ```
  =INT((A13+3)/4)
  ```
- perhaps it's easier to divide by 4 and round *up*; we have the [`CEILING` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093471?hl=en&ref_topic=3105474) for that:

  ```
  =CEILING(A13/4)
  ```

They'll both produce the same results:

[image]

---

A general trick to generate a formula like this one:

```
1-2 = -2
3-4 = -1
5-6 = 0
```

Your input is divided into buckets of size 2, so the first step is to divide by two:

```
1 -> 0.5
2 -> 1
3 -> 1.5
4 -> 2
5 -> 2.5
6 -> 3
```

Then, add or subtract a number such that the outcome is correct for the lowest or the highest number in the input 'bucket'. In this case, we can subtract 3:

```
1 -> 0.5 -> -2.5
2 -> 1   -> -2
3 -> 1.5 -> -1.5
4 -> 2   -> -1
5 -> 2.5 -> -0.5
6 -> 3   ->  0
```

Then, round up or down. In this case, up. So we have to

- divide by 2
- subtract 3
- round up

and our final formula becomes

```
=CEILING(A1/2 - 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is making use of the [`QUOTIENT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093436) function:

### Formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUOTIENT(B1:B17,4)+1)
```

### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: What is the B1:B17 portion?

Comment: That is a good question Steph, I'll look up my file and post a screenshot .

Comment: @Steph I noticed that my anser is not exactly what you want.....